# Is it possible to store the result of transformation in a variable (R Script/ Power Query like) in SQL server

Tags: r, sql-server

Is it possible to store the result of a transformation in a variable like R/Power query.

For example, with R/power query following can be achieved now

```
X<- table1
Y<- table2
Z<- table3
A<- X LEFT JOIN Y
B<- Z LEFT JOIN A
and so on ....
```

It is so much easier if this can be done in SQL server. It is much easier to store the result of a transformation in a variable to be utilized later in perpetuity within the code.

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider using SQL?

Comment: @anotherfred I am using SQL sever and doing the transformation in SQL server and currently wondering if I can still do R/Power Query like variables in SQL server when I do my data transformations in SQL server?

Comment: Temporary tables are usually used in SQL to store results temporarily, similar to the use of variables in other languages.